# Add only required stored procedures to EDMX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, entity-framework-4

I have two newly created stored procedures in my database. I tried to import those two stored procedures by going to Model Browser -> Function Imports -> Update Model from Database -> Add (tab) -> Selecting the newly created stored procedures under Stored Procedures and Functions -> dbo and clicking Finish button.
Note: I have checked 'Import Selected Stored Procedures and functions into the entity model' option.

The above step helped in adding the required stored procedures into my model/edmx.

But the problem I am facing is, it is also updating the other tables where there are few changes to one of the table where few columns were deleted in some table. This table has nothing to do with the stored procedures that I am importing. But it is asking me to update that table as well even though I have selected only the stored procedures.

Can someone please help me out why is this checking other tables which are not related to my newly added stored procedures even though I have selected to import only those stored procedures? how can I avoid other changes which are not relevant to my stored procedures?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is also updating the other tables where there are few changes to one of the table where few columns were deleted in some table"? What is "it"? If you can add an image to your post, which seems to be appropriate in your case, then that would help others to understand your issue better.

Comment: There is only one edmx file for the database.  So the edmx needs to be compatible for all tables.